# Clarification regarding passing arguments by reference

Tags: c++, reference

While reading about passing references to function as parameters, I found this article [passing arguments by reference](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) (and the code it talks about) which says at a point that:

```
void getSinCos(double degrees, double &sinOut, double &cosOut)
{
   //SOME PROCESSING WITH THE PARAMETERS
}
```

> The caller must pass in arguments to hold the updated outputs even if it doesn’t intend to use them. More importantly, the syntax is a bit unnatural, with both the input and output parameters being put together in the function call. It’s not obvious from the caller’s end that sin and cos are out parameters and will be changed. This is probably the most dangerous part of this method (as it can lead to mistakes being made). Some programmers and companies feel this is a big enough problem to advise not passing by reference this way, and using pass by address instead when mixing in and out parameters (which has a clearer syntax indicating whether a parameter is modifiable or not).

Sure we can't pass temporaries like argument **3** or some other integral/double literal when the parameters defined is a non-const reference but how can the modification of the input variable and restoring of the output in the same variable (as the changes are made to the original variable) be troublesome as this article points out? Can somebody please guide me as I am new to C++.

Comment: It could be troublesome if the caller of the function doesn't realize that the function will modify the arguments. Good naming (like the one in your example) as well as good documentation helps, and gives you something to point at if someone complaints about it (because not everyone reads documentation and keeps on guessing about behavior). With good naming and documentation, it's a problem of the user (who makes the call) and not for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, that problem can quickly become a problem for you if that user knowns where you live... And even faster is that user is you...

Comment: Some conventions can help, too, e. g. always group in and out parameters together (usually in parameters coming first - just as in your example), and as user, *always* expect values passed by reference being changed (if the function does not do so, the reference should always be `const`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something that people simply may not expect. Suppose you have this code:

```
int x = 5;
foobar(x);
```

What is the value of `x` after the function call? Most people would expect it to still be `5`, because barring undefined behavior, it can't change when passed by value. In C there isn't even pass by reference, so the value would always be `5`. Now in C++, there suddenly is passing by reference, and just from that snippet of code, you have no way of knowing whether `x` will change after the function call. You'd have to look at the actual signature of `foobar` for that.

It's not "dangerous" on its own, but if used poorly, it may lead to unclear and misleading code. Especially if you have a mix of parameters, some being out parameters, some not, and some having misleading names. In your example, the parameter names contain `out` to indicate that they're out parameters, and that's good style that mitigates this danger.

Contrast this with following snippet [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) explaining pass by reference how it is in C#:

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
// Output: 45
```

Here you instantly see that it's passed by reference because it says `ref number`.

Answer (score 3):

That article does not say anything about *"the modification of the input variable and restoring of the output in the same variable"* it only says that it is not obvious which arguments can be changed by the function call:

```
int x{};
int y{};
foo(x, y); // can you guess which variable has changed?
```

The part about pass by address having a "clearer syntax indicating whether a parameter is modifiable or not" is complete bullshit though. Not only it suffers from the same problem as pass by reference, but it also implies that some arguments can be optional and possible ownership transfer

```
int x{};
int y{};
foo(&x, &y); // can you guess which variable has changed?
foo(nullptr, &y); // can you guess whether this is correct usage?
foo(&x, &y); // can you be sure that foo won't delete pointer to x?
```

To be on the safe side one can use something like explicit pass by (const) reference:

```
int x{};
int y{};
foo(::std::as_const(x), y); // alright, x should not be changed inside
```

Comment: Entirely agree on the 'bullshit' part. The 'safe side' won't work if foo only accepts a non-const reference - and in case of appropriate overloads (*such* ones might not be a good idea, but still...), it might lead to calling another one than without.

Comment: not really complete bullshit, but i think i got your point. Even simpler example is `f(x)` where if you dont know if `x` is a pointer or not, you also dont know if `f` is modifying something even if `x` is passed by value

Comment: btw "can you be sure that foo won't delete pointer to x?" yes I would safely assume that, because if it does then i would consider it as broken ;)